# problems with .env and loader.php files

Tags: php, web-development-server

I am redesigning a website for a client. They provided me with the server login where I was able to download all the files via FTP. I uploaded them all to Heroku but I come across this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException: Unable to 
read the environment file at /var/www/public/.env. in 
/var/www/public/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Loader.php:76 Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/public/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Loader.php(52): 
Dotenv\Loader->ensureFileIsReadable() #1 
/var/www/public/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php(91): 
Dotenv\Loader->load() #2 
/var/www/public/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php(48): 
Dotenv\Dotenv->loadData() #3 /var/www/public/inc/config.php(11): 
Dotenv\Dotenv->load() #4 /var/www/public/index.php(2): 
require('/var/www/public...') #5 {main} thrown in 
/var/www/public/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Loader.php on line 76
```

Here is line 73-78 of the Loader.php file:

```
  protected function ensureFileIsReadable()
  {
    if (!is_readable($this->filePath) || !is_file($this->filePath)) {
        throw new InvalidPathException(sprintf('Unable to read the environment file at %s.', $this->filePath));
    }
  }
```

And lastly the .env has db info from the previous developer but do I need to change these values if all I want to do is design changes?

Comment: Im having a very similar issue. Have you found a fix for this?